# Any data on how many users change passwords after a breach notifcation?

Tags: passwords, breach

Does anyone know of any study or any data whatsoever which might indicate how many users actually change their passwords after they have been notified that their credentials appeared in a breach?

Comment: Can we assume that you mean web services and not corporate accounts?

Comment: Have you looked this up? I'm finding hits ... https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-youre-sticking-with-passwords-that-have-already-been-hacked/

Comment: That google study is only if a user attempts to use a previously compromised password, not whether or not they changed it after they had been notified that their personal account credentials were compromised. Yes this is all in reference to web services.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are concluding that. The Google paper is about changes after being notified, as tracked by their extension.

Comment: I'd hope that it would be a best practice for the provider to force users to pick a different password - to actually compare old and new and require that the new password be different, as a one-time assurance activity (at which point the answer to your question would be a cheery "100%!" ;) But I can see why some orgs might choose otherwise, though.

Comment: The best thing an organisation could do is to generate new passwords for all compromised accounts and instruct their users/clients to use the "I forgot my password" mechanism.

Comment: @Jeroen I wouldn't generate new passwords - I would disable the password, effectively locking the account and forcing a password reset. Also, the question seems to be about a password leaked in any breach. While I would certainly freeze accounts that were compromised on my own service, I doubt I would freeze an account who's credentials were leaked from another service, even if matching.